# Ionic 2 Native plugins fails to install

Tags: java, cordova, ionic2

When ever I try to add a native plugin on Ionic2 project - the CLI throws error as :

A native plugin is requested to be installed -

ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

```
Installing "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" for android


Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Unzipping C:\Users\<user_name>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip to C:\Users\<user_name>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.
14.1-all\53l0mv9mggp9q5m2ip574m21oh

Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:160)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$400(Install.java:29)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:70)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-compat':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (F:\<path>\EventShareApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)


Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner':Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (F:\<user_name>\EventShareApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)    

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 enter code here
```

I tried with different native plugins - but each time the error remains same.

Comment: I don't think this is related to ionic2. For some reason Java can't unzip the plugins. Could be a problem with directory permissions or with your Java installation.

Comment: @Schlaus Yes you are correct. The issue popped up for not getting latest Android SDK. I listed a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This has reference to my earlier question at: [Ionic2 - Android build failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938932/ionic2-android-build-failed/41949690#41949690)

The issue was with the unavailability of latest Android SDK.

Basically as per 'https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/' - As of cordova-android@4.0.0, Cordova for Android projects are built using Gradle. Earlier it was built using Apache Ant.

Now Gradle looks for latest Android SDK. When I removed the android platform and added again with `ionic platform add android` command - the CLI listed that the latest Android SDK ( in my case it was SDK 24 ) was not installed.

I installed the required SDK version using Android SDK Manager and subsequent add of Android Platform along with the cordova plugin smoothly installed without any error.

The CLI printed the following -

```
..ionic plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin

Fetching plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin" via npm

Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:clean
:CordovaLib:clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.611 secs

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
```

If anyone faces the same issue - please let me know if updating the SDK to the latest version helps .